# Invidious API create token

Tags: api

I try to use Invidious API with authenticated route. For this, i've generated new token with this URL : `https://invidio.us/authorize_token?scopes=GET:preferences`.

The response is like this : `{"session":"v1:XXXXX","scopes":["GET:preferences"],"signature":"XXXX"}`

But, the token generated (`session`) don't work. I try with simple GET on preferences route, and i've an error `Request must be authenticated` :(

Anyone have already use their API and work with auth route ?

Thank you !

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've actually been struggling with this the past week, and I even deployed a self hosted instance because I thought that would fix it... I was wrong of course.

Here's how the Authentication header should look like:

`Authentication: {"session":"v1:XXXXX","scopes":["GET:preferences/*"],"signature":"XXXX"}`

The full token is the json that is provided.

The scope needs to include a `*` or a specific identifier for example in the case of playlists as mentioned in the [examples here](https://github.com/omarroth/invidious/wiki/Authenticated-Endpoints) . So your `authorize_token` request should look like:

`https://invidio.us/authorize_token?scopes=GET:preferences*`

or

`https://invidio.us/authorize_token?scopes=GET:preferences/*`.

If you want all scopes that would be `:*`. Make sure not to forget the colon.